# Python Follow Window.Location Redirect

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I created a quick python program that returns the title for the final destination of a URL.

```
def get_title(url):
    try:
        req = urllib2.Request(url) 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(req))
        return soup.title.string.encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip().replace('\n','')
    except:
        print('Generic Exception for ' + url + ', ' + traceback.format_exc())
```

This code works fine but one of the URLs has a redirect that is done via a `window.location` and because of this my script cannot follow that path. Is there a simple way to have it follow `window.location` redirects as well?

Comment: Iterate over the scripts, find the text `window.location = "..."` using a proper regular expression, go to the matched string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using RegEx to match for `window.location` and extracting the URL

```
def get_title(url):
    try:
        req = urllib2.Request(url) 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(req))
        redirMatch = re.match(r'.*?window\.location\s*=\s*\"([^"]+)\"', str(soup), re.M|re.S)
        if(redirMatch and "http" in redirMatch.group(1)):
            url = redirMatch.group(1)
            return get_title(url)
        else:
            return soup.title.string.encode('ascii', 'ignore').strip().replace('\n','')
```